# How to get Vue app container div attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I have a page which is being generated by my app in java (SSR) depending on some data (e.g. a publisher for some entity). I would like to create some sort of a reusable Vue component that would call an API method and request some data about the entity that is currently opened. Also in some cases there could be more than one such component on one page.

The only thing I cannot really figure out being a most-of-the-time backend developer - is how to tell a component which entity I'm trying to get. The only solution that comes to my mind is to generate the parent `<div class="my-vue-component"><div>` with an additional attribute, e.g. `<div class="my-vue-component" publisher-id="123"><div>`.

But I cannot find if there is a way to access that attribute from inside the Vue instance. (Please note that I don't have a fixed id for this div as there can be many such components on the same page referring to different data).

Any kind of advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for [`components-props`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).

You can define a prop like

```
Vue.component('blog-post', {
 // camelCase in JavaScript
 props: ['postTitle'],
```

Your SSR code should then be generating:

```
<!-- kebab-case in HTML -->
<blog-post post-title="hello!"></blog-post>
```

Inside the component methods you can access the passed in value using `this.postTitle`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the previous answer, you will need to use props. Although since you will pass down data to multiple components and the data can change, there should be a way to respond to those changes.

For that, you will have to bind the `prop` with a reactive variable in your page/parent component.

So your SSR code should look like

```html
<my-vue-component :publisher-id="openId"></blog-post>
```

And inside your page/parent component will reside the `openId`, which you can change as needed, and your component will re-render if prop passed to it changes.

```js
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      openId:1
    } 
  }
}
```